# SharePoint 2010 designer workflow multillevel approval

Tags: sharepoint-designer

SharePoint 2010 designer workflow - start approval process action. It is multiple level approval. At third/last stage, it should be just approve (Reject option should not be present) How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Reject button cannot be hidden as this is a default design of the Start Approval Process action form. SharePoint Designer Workflows are not designed for high customization. They are available for those customization that cannot be achieved with out of the box available list workflows.

If you need such a customization that at every last stage of approval, the Reject button must hide then Visual Studio Workflow is the best approach.

Even if you create a Task List and a custom Task EditForm.aspx that has Approve and Reject button created by you then still it would be very difficult to indicate when is the final approval stage to hide your Reject button.